# Проблема с библиотеками в Unity после обновления

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

Вчера обновил юнити до 2020.3.30f1 (до этого была 28), на следующие сутки мне пришлось восстановить систему через точку восстановления, после этого юнити всё ещё показывал версию 30,но я на всякий случай решил переустановить юнити, после переустановки зашёл в проект и он начал сыпать этими ошибками, после попробовал откатить версию до 28, откатил, проблема осталась, потом решил взять папку Library с другого проекта, который я ещё не запускал на 30 версии и перенес в текущий (т.е. был проект, который был создан на 28 версии, потом запущен на 30, потом опять запущен на 28 и папка library была от другого проекта 28 версии), но проблема осталась
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: assets -> Reimport all не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете пакет, который не импортирован, попробуйте написать:
`using (NameSpace который отсутствует)`

Comment: Ошибка не с моим скриптом, это из библиотек юнити

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в доступе к папке, т.е. Unity не мог изменить некоторые файлы проекта и в итоге вышла такая ошибка, решил путём переноса папки в другое место